# Excel Formula to calculate percetage for multiple row and sum the total percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uauni.jpg)I need excel formula.

I have 6 column and each column should calculate percentage of 50% when number is entered and 7th column should SUM those results.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Not getting formula- if use formula as =50%*B12 ( I get error saying its referring  to same cell.)

Comment: You can't put a formula in the same cell you're going to input your value in.

Comment: Just sum the six columns and then take half...unless I'm missing something.

Comment: cheek the image attached

Comment: can some one show sample please

Comment: Input and output cells should be separate. For example, input your values in cells B2 to G2. Then put your formula in cells H2 to M2 (In H2, `=0.5*B2`, etc.). On cell N2, get the sum of H2 to M2.

Comment: So I put values from B2 to G2 and In H2 I need formula which should display 50% of B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,H2. and in I2 it should show sum

Comment: How about: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1)*0.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear what you are after but it may be this.

In column G (7th column), 1st row, put:

```
=sum(.5*A1 + .5*B1 + .5*C1 + .5*D1 + .5*E1 + .5*F1)
```

Then copy down to all the other rows you have.

Comment: So I put values from B2 to G2 and In H2 I need formula which should display 50% of B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,H2. and in I2 it should show sum.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" the answer as working. It gives us "helpers" reputation points. Thanks.